# Copying and Pasting data using Cells / Row Column reference in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I'm having difficulty copying and pasting data in Excel 2013 VBA using row column references.

Here's a snippet of my code that fails (creates an error message):
"Application Defined or object defined error"

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(3, 3)).Copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1,1))
```

Here's an alternative version that works (copies the range A1:C3 from one worksheet to the other:

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:C3").Copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
```

Why am I fixated on the rows/columns method? Because I want to be able to copy and paste ranges where all of the row and column references are variables. This is for my personal knowledge.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry about that, added an error message.

Comment: `Cells` refers to the active sheet so `Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cells` on its own will refer to the `ActiveSheet`, you should watch your variable qualifications. Also here I have used `CodeNames` [Worksheet.CodeName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837552.aspx%20Worksheet.CodeName) for the sheets which defends against user changing worksheet names.

I believe what you want is this...

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

   Sheet2.Range(Sheet2.Cells(1, 1), Sheet2.Cells(3, 3)).Copy Sheet1.Cells(1, 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: Tested and confirmed. This will be massively helpful and now it's in my StackOverflow history in case I ever forget.  Thanks!